# Google app script returning thread and messages - Probable Loop/Index error - Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, try-catch, nullreferenceexception

For some reason, my Google App script that parses the daily status email from our SCADA system no longer returns the lineNumber property which used to be provided as a parameter returned with the App Script Try/Catch error object.  As a result, I am having a difficult time tracing down the source of the "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error which is trapped. I wonder if someone more experienced in working with gmail might see something obvious I am missing.

The script provides a critical link between our SCADA and live website which posts real-time daily data into decades of historical operational data.  Because it works with live data and runs in the middle of the night, I am not around for supervised debugging, and because the error is trapped in a try/catch the location is not automatically reported in the execution/debug logs.  A simplified code block is shown below:

```js
// scan the subject lines of all messages in the inbox -> get daily status reports
  var thread = GmailApp.search('in:Inbox subject:"<<<<search string goes here>>>>"');
  var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(thread);
  
// verify that only one qualifying email is available
  if (thread.length != 1 | messages.length != 1) {
    // send warning email to cleanup inbox and process data manually
    errorEmail(inboxError);
    return;
  }
  
// process message  
  for (var i = 0 ; i < messages.length; i++) {
    // verify messages[i] <> null
    if(!messages[i]) return;
    for (var j = 0; j < messages[i].length; j++) {
      // message processing loop
      var subject = messages[i][j].getSubject();
      var body = messages[i][j].getPlainBody();
      ...
    }
  }
```

The script has historically been successful in parsing and posting the target data, but recently the ".length" property error has surfaced and prevents the script from completing "gracefully". I have not made any code changes to trigger this error and suspect it may be caused by some change in the underlying script engine.

Given that the error probably results from attempting to return the .length property from a null object, I wonder if my i or j messages indices are being null-tested incorrectly.  I know that there should be only one daily status report in the gmail inbox, and that the error occurs when i=2 and j=1.  My guess is that the messages loop must have worked properly in earlier iterations.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: either thread or messages is undefined.  Please use the debugger to find out which

Comment: Agreed that an element of messages[] is null, but the messages array IS defined.  I think I am overstepping the bounds of the messages array by incrementing the i index too far, probably in the "for (var j = 0; j < messages[i].length; j++)" loop.

Comment: The problem I have is that I can't observe the script executing in real time, the e.lineNumber property is no longer available from the try/catch block, and my execution logs are blank when I look at the previous night's execution.  This message retrieval snippet is common, but I have no intuition about google's thread/message structure.

Comment: This `(thread.length != 1 | messages.length != 1)` should be `(thread.length != 1 || messages.length != 1)`

Comment: Cooper, thank you for catching my javascript syntax error ( single pipe | vs double pipe || for logical OR).  In my native language, | usually works fine, but not in this case.  Whereas the nested index loop pattern I borrowed from web code as an example makes sense for situations where multiple messages are retrieved, in my application there will be only one message retrieved and iterating through an array of  messages is overly complicated.  But my code now exits gracefully, and thanks for the javascript syntax check.

Comment: Second oldest programming mistake in the book! In addition to the || vs | logical OR syntax mistake Cooper pointed out, when I went over the entire 1K line script in detail I discovered my array index (i,j) bounds problem was caused by inadvertently using i as an index variable for another loop within the scope of the (i,j) outer for loop. Duh! and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
function myfunck() {
  var thread = GmailApp.search('in:Inbox subject:"Keep In Inbox"');
  var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(thread);
  if (thread.length != 1 || messages.length != 1) {
    Logger.log('Email Error');
    return;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    if (!messages[i]) return;
    for (var j = 0; j < messages[i].length; j++) {
      var subject = messages[i][j].getSubject();
      var body = messages[i][j].getPlainBody();
    }
  }
}
```